# Run a project from another project in visual studio

Tags: wpf

im tring to open a window in wpf app from another file.
ive added it to the main project but i cant run it.
im trying to do something like this: 
this(//the main window) = WpfApplication(//other project).MainWindow;
is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you've added the the project you need to use to your solution you may also need to add a reference to that project in your original project as well.

Comment: i've added the reference to the project i just need the comand